# Unable to upload image

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to upload image using following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("form_upload")).sendKeys("\\images\\Penguins.jpg");
driver.findElement(By.id("form_upload")).submit();
```

Following is html snippet:

```
<a class="fileinput-button upload-photo-button">
  <span>Form Thumbnail</span>
  <input id="form_upload" type="file" name="form[upload]">
   <input id="form_upload_purpose" type="hidden" value="upload_form_thumbnail" name="form[upload_purpose]">
</a>
```

After code execution, following text is displayed in browser:

```
{"errors":"Template can't be blank."}
```

Could someone please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you do have form tags, dont you?

Comment: Do you not have "Submit" or "Upload" button in form ?

Comment: It has "Save" button.

Comment: Then you should click the "Save" button instead submitting the form using Selenium.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see "\images\Penguins.jpg" in the form_upload input field after the send keys is executed ?  This believe this input filed is disabled to you would need to try another approach by trying to using Windows forms if you are trying to test on a windows machine.

```
 SendKeys.SendWait(@"Penquins.png");
    SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```